# pypy5.6 install confluent_kafka cause: undefined symbol PyUnicode_FromFormat Error

Tags: python, pypy, confluent-platform

When install confluent_kafka on pypy5.6, its has an error of : undefined symbol PyUnicode_FromFormat Error, i dont know how its happend ？

the os is: CentOs5.6

the full error output is :

```
Python 2.7.12 (aff251e543859ce4508159dd9f1a82a2f553de00, Nov 12 2016, 08:50:18)
[PyPy 5.6.0 with GCC 6.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import confluent_kafka
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/local/pypy/site-packages/confluent_kafka/**init**.py", line 2, in 
>       from .cimpl import *
>   ImportError: unable to load extension module '/usr/local/pypy/site-packages/confluent_kafka/cimpl.pypy-41.so': /usr/local/pypy/site-packages/confluent_kafka/cimpl.pypy-41.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicode_FromFormat

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I build the pypy with in the docker, and install confluent_kafka in the same docker, test in the docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PyUnicode_FromFormat` is not implemented so far inside PyPy.  We'll get to it at some point (maybe soon if you have an example that requires it).  You can also contribute it directly, if you want to get involved.

FWIW it is implemented in the `py3.5` branch implementing Python 3.5, but not in trunk (supporting Python 2.7).  Trunk only implements `PyString_FromFormat`.  It's mostly a matter of back-porting the implementation, and "downgrading" the C code: in `py3.5` it comes from CPython 3.5, so for trunk we'd need the same C code from CPython 2.7 instead.

Comment: thanks !! i think i use another version of python while be fast !

Comment: The PyMongo BSON C extension needs this functionality. Unfortunately, the pure-python fallback fails on some timestamps in their oplog and the recommended solution by mongo devs is to use the C extension, which is unsupported in PyPy as of now.

Ref: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/issues/279#issuecomment-147862759

Comment: ``PyUnicode_FromFormat()`` is provided in PyPy2 5.9.

Comment: Thanks! Naturally, there are a few more missing functions now that that one was implemented. I'll look into implementing them since it all seems pretty simple.